# Error trying to save image in file system in Azure Server - A generic error occurred in GDI+

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-roles

I am trying to save an image in an azure worker roles' file system.

This is my code :

```
BlobStream inputImage = inputBlob.OpenRead();
Stream inputStream = inputImage;
    string inputPath = "F:\\approot\\input\\" + imageId; //Image id is 582

    inputStream.Position = 0;
                    //save image to physicall file
                    var img = Image.FromStream(inputStream);
                    string imagePath = pInputPath + "\\" + pImageId + ".png";
                    img.Save(imagePath, ImageFormat.Png);
                    var xml = "";
```

This problem came all of the sudden, my application was working but suddenly it started crashing at this point.

Comment: What is the value of `pInputPath`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the issue is with the f drive. You'll find that, occasionally, `e:` and `f:` may change upon restart. Since you claimed that things were working, and then *suddenly started crashing*, I'm thinking that, if you rdp into your role instance, you'll find that `approot` is now on `e:` instead of `f:`.

There should be an environment variable, `RoleRoot`, that you can use for determining what drive your `approot` is on:

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("RoleRoot");
```

Comment: This will return the drive or the full path to my solution?